# Javascript this point to last object instance

Tags: javascript, object, this, instance

Before all, sorry for my bad english.

I'm having problem with the context of a jquery Plugin i'm developing.
Each instance I make of the plugin below, this points to last object.
Example:

```
var a = $("#a").EscribirConAdjuntos();
var b = $("#b").EscribirConAdjuntos();
var c = $("#c").EscribirConAdjuntos();
```

It results that a and b modifies the c object, I would try to explain better, but I don't know why.

If i do a.setText("Text A"); it will modify the textarea appended by the instance stored in c.

```
(function(window, $){
    var pluginName = 'EscribirConAdjuntos';
    if(typeof $ === "undefined")
        return console.error('No esta añadida la librería jquery.js');

    var defaults = {
        btnGuardar : false,
        onGuardar : $.noop,
        onActualizar : $.noop,
        texto : false,
        media : false,
    };



    /* Constructor principal */
    var Plugin = function ($el, options){
        this.o = $.extend( {}, defaults, options);
        this.$.el = $el;
        // I add this textarea
        this.$.textarea = $('<textarea></textarea>').appendTo(this.$.el);
        return this;

    };
    Plugin.prototype = {
        $:{},
        setText : function(text){
             this.textarea.val(text);
        }
        /* Some functions */

    };




    $.fn[pluginName] = function(options, args){
        var $this = $(this);

        var plugin = $this.data(pluginName);
        if(!plugin){
            plugin = new Plugin($this, options);
            $this.data(pluginName, plugin);
            return plugin;
        } else {
            if(plugin[options] && typeof plugin[options] == 'function')
                return plugin[options].apply(plugin,args);
            else
                return plugin;
        }
    };
})(window, jQuery);
```

Comment: Could you add the code for one of the modifying functions?

Comment: @MildlySerios code Added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the `this` value of the function. The problem is the `Plugin.prototype.$` object. `$` property of all the instances of `Plugin` constructor refer to the same object, i.e. when you  reset the value of `el` and `textarea` properties of the `$` object, they will be reset for all instances.

```
> a === b
false
> a.$ === b.$
true
```

Define the `$` property in the constructor.

```
/* Constructor principal */
var Plugin = function ($el, options){
    this.o = $.extend( {}, defaults, options);
    this.$ = {};
    this.$.el = $el;
    // I add this textarea
    this.$.textarea = $('<textarea></textarea>').appendTo(this.$.el);
    return this;
};
Plugin.prototype = {
    // $:{},
    setText : function(text){
       this.$.textarea.val(text);
    }
};
```

Comment: This is exactly the problem. I actually had to make a stripped down fiddle to understand this, because although I do work with vanilla prototypes every now and then, this specific case never came up for me and I couldn't make sense of it right away. It makes sense now, though. Thank you for putting together the answer!

Comment: Thanks,  that was the problem,  i found just before comming here back.  what a headache